# Save Bin and Last4 in Database when creating order - WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

I need to save in the database the Bin and Last4 of the card informed by the user in the transparent checkout when creating order.

I am trying to do this insertion when saving the request, but it is not working because it is writing as: NULL

[image]

Javascript

```
$('.woocommerce-checkout, #order_review').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
// console.log($('input[name=pagarme_card_hash]').val());
var cardNumber = $('#pagarme-card-number').val();
var pagarmeCardNumber = cardNumber.replace(/ /g, ''); // remove spaces
var bin = pagarmeCardNumber.slice(0, 6);
var last4 = pagarmeCardNumber.slice(-4);

console.log('pagarmeCardNumber: ' + pagarmeCardNumber);
console.log('bin: ' + bin);
console.log('last4: ' + last4);

$.ajax({

    type: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        bin: bin,
        last4: last4,
        action: 'idx_save_bin_last4'
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('success');

    },
    error: function (error){
        console.log('error');
        console.log(error);
    }
});
return false;
});
```

functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_idx_save_bin_last4', 'idx_save_bin_last4' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_idx_save_bin_last4', 'idx_save_bin_last4' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'idx_save_bin_last4', 10, 3 );
function idx_save_bin_last4($post_id)
{
   $bin = $_POST['bin'];
   $last4 = $_POST['last4'];
   $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

   if ("shop_order" != $post_type ) {
     return;
   }
   update_post_meta($post_id, '_order_bin', $bin);
   update_post_meta($post_id, '_order_last4', $last4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No offense, but I would never buy anything from your site with code like that, and using unfiltered POST vars.

Consider using Stripe API to handle PAN data, then all you have to worry about is a transaction, invoice, customer, and subscription hashes.  No CC data ever touches your server.